# Хранение в БД текста со ссылками на медиа-файлы

Tags: php, json

Категорически всех приветствую!
Ребят, мне действительно нужен ваш совет.
Суть вопроса будет лежать в правильном хранении данных в БД (скорее текстовых данных).

Итак, на сайте имеется, к примеру, личная переписка где пользователи могут обмениваться сообщениями, а так же, музыкой и фотографиями. Все работает на ура, но загруженные файлы отображаются под сообщениями, что мне, по ряду причин, не нравится и посему мне пришла в голову идея отображать файлы под определенными участками текста.
К примеру, пользователь написал текст, а под него добавил фото (мой личный визуальный редактор для этих целей), затем написал еще текст и добавил музыкальный файл. Но для такого подхода необходимо хранить разметку в самой БД, что мне не нравится т.к. разметка со временем может поменяться или еще что-либо....

Казалось бы, что можно поступить иначе, а именно:

Заменить теги в тексте на какие-либо сгенерированные ключи и по регВыражению заменять его на соответствующие теги. Как по мне, так вовсе коряво, да и не хочется регулярные выражения применять для подобных целей.

И мне в очередной раз пришла идея:

Записывать сообщения в БД в простом текстовом виде, но когда пользователь прикрепляет файл, то отправляемые данные на сервер поставлять уже в `JSON` кодированном виде, примерно след. вида:

```js
[
  {"text": "Некоторый текст"},
  {"img": "Сюда можно добавить объект с шириной, высотой и источником изображения"},
  {"text": "Другая часть текста"},
  {"audio": "Здесь объект содержащий инфу о музыкальном файле"},
  {"text": "Еще текст"}
]
```

И так как на выходе мы имеем JSON, то соответствующим образом обрабатываем его на стороне сервера и записываем уже обработанные данные в таком же формате в БД и когда нужно будет отобразить текст, то мы можем перед тем как отдать содержимое пользователю подготовить соответствующую разметку (разумеется, после того как получили данные из БД применить функцию `json_decode`).

Что мне из этого нравится:

Файлами можно крутить вертеть как душе угодна, вплоть до отображения файлов под всем текстом в том порядке в каком хочется.
Оперирую с удалением, изменением файлов, а так же редактированием текста, не нужно прибегать к рег. выражениям, которые неудобно в данном случае.
Файлы с легкостью можно будет поместить в любые теги и изменения будут осуществлены везде.

Что мне не нравится:

Хоть и сообщения будут `JSON` кодированы не во всей таблице, но все же, меня смущает нагрузка на сервер, а именно постоянное декодирование и разбор. Насколько это критично?

Какой вы можете дать совет по этому поводу? Что скажете по поводу описанного мной подхода? Что бы вы изменили в моем подходе? И как с вашей точки зрения это может отразиться на производительности? Или, может быть, у вас есть более универсальная идея для этой цели?

Буду очень признателен за отклики!

Comment: Кодирование-декодирование, думаю, не очень критично. Точно быстрее, чем регулярки. Есть другая проблема - сложности валидации. Вам придется не просто раскодировать строку, Вам придется после проверять каждый элемент на допустимость.

Comment: Перед записью в БД данные будут проверяться на допустимость жестко, а именно, будет осуществлена проверка на `XSS` и прочая, а при выводе все проще будет. Все данные проверены и нужно только вывести их правильно. Да, разумеется, нужно будет из полученного массива отделить текст от файлов. Вы думаете это  критично? Зато скрипт приобретет большую гибкость, как по мне!

Comment: Критичность зависит от масштабов приложения и его популярности :) Я как раз о том, что json_encode / json_decode вряд ли окажутся "бутылочным горлышком" в Вашей системе. Будут места и потяжелее.

Comment: На самом деле, проект рассчитывается на большую посещаемость. Тем не менее, я привередлив к производительности. Даже и не знаю, хочется чтобы пользователю было удобно, приятно пользоваться сайтом!

Comment: Конечно здорово выбирать из базы json с аудио/видео, которое никто смотреть не будет, а мегабайты серверной памяти откусит. Какую такую гибкость скрипт обретёт что-то не понятно. Куда уж гибче выдавать всё без всякого разбора, и аудио там всякое так прямо-поточным методом из blob-об в браузер.

Comment: Это не каша, а напротив! В любом случае, фото и аудио будут загружены (т.к. пользователь это сделает) вот только вопрос где они будут отображаться, под всем текстом или же там где он захотел (в том числе, по его желанию, он может его и под всем текстом разместить). Плюс в том, что пользователь может дать описание какой то фотографии и выложить ее, затем дать описание другой и т.д. читателю будет удобнее, нежели все в куче будет под сообщением. В любом случае, он может все и под текстом выложить, интерфейс позволяет это

Comment: И ко всему этому, я не собираюсь хранить бинарный код в БД, а только ссылки на файлы, если что!

Comment: Так вроде и сейчас никто не испытывает трудности с подписями и картинки остаются на своём месте. Посмотрите на любой форум, на этом сайте вопросы и ответы. Вряд ли они переводят текст своего редактора сообщений в json. Тем более используется какой-либо язык разметки, всяко лучше json-а подходящий для этих целей. Все ссылки на дополнительные материалы естественным образом сразу же встроены в текст сообщения.

Comment: Просто ссылки так и будут вставляться (разметкой). А почему я должен делать как у всех? Я хочу сделать лучше, я хочу отличаться!

Comment: Там где у людей сразу готовое сообщение, Вам придётся собирать его из кусочков своего json

Comment: Только в том случае, если пользователь загрузил тот или иной файл и разместил его именно в определенном участке текста, а не, скажем, под всем текстом.

Comment: Т.е. хотите сказать Ваша метода хорошо работает, когда иной файл вне текста. Как тогда насчёт гибкости? Как же вы собрались делать редактор и тем более с картинками и без разметки? С чего вдруг решили, что разметка обрабатывается регулярными выражениями?

Comment: Я клоню к тому, что данные будут json кодироваться только если хотя бы один из файл будет размещен не под текстом, а внутри. В других случаях, в таблице будет храниться просто текст. Понимаете о чем я? И если принимать во внимание этот факт, то становится ясно, что большинство сообщений будет храниться просто как текст

Comment: Думаю тут вопрос как раз в том самом красивом редакторе, который будет таскать картинку по тексту. Каково будет внутреннее представление текста с картинками на клиенте. В виде подобного js массива. тут довольно весело получается с перетеканием блоков текста из одного объекта в этом массиве в другой по мере движения картинки. Хотя тут при любом хранении думаю примерно одинакова сложность... Короче - если ты уже представляешь как реализовать графический редактор - сделай наброски, там еще куча подводных камней может выплыть, которые могут сильно сказаться и на выборе способа передачи и хранения.

Comment: Надо каждый элемент сообщения представить в виде поля json . Т.е. что-то вроде DOM html.

Comment: Да, раз уж передавать массив объектов, посмотри в сторону Multipart content type. По сути он сделан как раз для последовательной передачи нескольких объектов в текстовом протоколе (http, smtp, ...). По крайней мере можно реализовать на сервере последовательный прием частей и запись в БД без хранения в памяти всего набора объектов сразу. Хотя смотря на чем писать... php шибко умный, наверняка захочет сам все заранее прочитать и разбросать по переменным...

Comment: Редактор уже готов. Ввод текста полностью ложится на JS и поэтому никаких лишних тегов, только переносы <br> а файлы просто в блочных тегах хранятся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без тегов: хранить текст отдельно от файлов, а в мета-инфе файла указывать offset его положения в тексте от начала текста.

Можно в одном JSON, можно в реляционной БД – как хотите.

```
{
  "text": "Весь текст на много строк",
  "attachments": [
    {"position":12, "type":"image", "src":"ololo", "w":12, "h":34},
    {"position":34, "type":"audio", "src":"ololo", "w":12, "h":34},
    {"position":56, "type":"video", "src":"ololo", "w":12, "h":34},
  ]
}
```

Редактируют визуально – на место вложений ставится html для их отображения.

Редактируют исходный код – на месте вложений ставятся теги.

При сохранении позиции пересчитываются, разумеется. Плюсы: со временем разметку (теги) можно менять безобидно для контента; можно отображать файлы на их месте в тексте, или вне его – при одном и том же содержании БД. Минусы: надо реализовать обновление позиций при редактировании без ошибок.

Comment: Меня посещала подобная идея, но поразмыслив какое-то время, я не уверен в том, что это совсем то что нужно. Еще и в мета-инфу что-то писать, мне кажется, совсем заморочено)

Comment: Думаю так не вариант, ибо при редактировании, при добавлении/удалении какого либо текста необходимо пересчитывать позицию вложений. не думаю что это сильно нагрузит, но потенциальных ошибок в таких операциях много.

Comment: Если не хотите заморачиваться, переезжайте на WordPress )

Comment: Лучше всё-таки как в вопросе. Просто при перетаскивании картинки, допустим в первый text, он разбивается на два text-а: один до картинки, второй после. И никакой доп. инфы по позиционированию не надо.

Comment: И вывод сообщения идёт блок за блоком. Attachment-ы сразу же оказываются на своём месте. Без постоянной, символ-за-символом консультации attachments -а не вставить ли в эту позицию чего-нибудь. И без последующего рассовывания их в уже выведенный текст.

Comment: @banme в чём преимущество двух кусков текста, хранимых где-то независимо, над единым текстом и позицией (где его потенциально надо разбить)? Не думаю, что может понадобится однажды напр. только текст между второй и третьей картинкой.

Comment: Вообще-то они хранятся не независимо, а вместе в одном json-е.  Текст с тегами разметки просто заменяется на структуру json. Как html в браузере на DOM, где каждая noda имеет свой тип и идут они в порядке, заданном текстом html.

Answer (score 2):

> Меня смущает нагрузка на сервер

Маркер бесполезного вопроса N1. Как только речь заходит о воображаемой нагрузке на сервер, никакой конструктивной дискуссии не получится. Реальные проблемы с производительностью обсуждать можно. Воображаемые, не имеющие под собой никакой реальной основы - нет смысла.

> не хочется регулярные выражения применять

Маркер бесполезного вопроса N2. Понятия "хочется" и "не хочется" не имеют отношения к программированию. Это скорее из области психологии.

> А почему я должен делать как у всех? Я хочу сделать лучше, я хочу отличаться!

Маркер бесполезного вопроса N3. Взаимоисключающие параграфы "Меня интересует мнение сообщества, но я не хочу делать так, как делает сообщество!".

Comment: Я Вас понял, мне будет над чем подумать на досуге!

Comment: Зачем так человека пугать. Особенно 2 последних страшилки за уши притянуты.